# Parse JSON response using jQuery

Tags: ajax, json, object, jsonp

I'm dealing with a JSON Response in one of my applications. I have established a connection using jsonp successfully. But I'm not able to parse my response.

Code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function($) {
var url = 'http://cooktv.sndimg.com/webcook/sandbox/perf/topics.json';

$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
       console.log(json.topics);
       $("#nav").html('<a href="">'+json.topics+"</a>");
    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
    }
});

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Output i'm getting:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Response Example:

```
callback({"topics":[{"name":"topic","content":[{"link_text":"link","link_src":"http://www.foodnetwork.com/"},{"link_text":"link","link_src":"http://www.hgtv.com/"},{"link_text":"link","link_src":"http://www.diynetwork.com/"},{"link_text":"link","link_src":"http://www.cookingchanel.com/"},{"link_text":"link","link_src":"http://www.travelchannel.com/"},{"link_text":"link","link_src":"http://www.food.com/"}]},{"name":"topic2","content":[{"link_text":"link","link_src":"http://www.google.com/"},{"link_text":"link","link_src":"http://www.yahoo.com/"},{"link_text":"link","link_src":"http://www.aol.com/"},{"link_text":"link","link_src":"http://www.msn.com/"},{"link_text":"link","link_src":"http://www.facebook.com/"},{"link_text":"link","link_src":"http://www.twitter.com/"}]},{"name":"topic3","content":[{"link_text":"link","link_src":"http://www.a.com/"},{"link_text":"link","link_src":"http://www.b.com/"},{"link_text":"link","link_src":"http://www.c.com/"},{"link_text":"link","link_src":"http://www.d.com/"},{"link_text":"link","link_src":"http://www.e.com/"},{"link_text":"link","link_src":"http://www.f.com/"}]}]});
```

I want in the form of :

Topic: Link

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
success: function(json) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(json.topics));
   $.each(json.topics, function(idx, topic){
     $("#nav").html('<a href="' + topic.link_src + '">' + topic.link_text + "</a>");
   });
},
```

Comment: I am getting a response like this
`[{id: 1, message: "sdfsdf", message_for: 1, message_by: 2, created_at: "2015-08-29 08:22:02",…},…]` There is no variable like topics as specified in the question.

Answer (score 6):

it's very simple to parse JSON response into normal HTML. Via JavaScript we can do it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Create Object from JSON String</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.name + ", " + obj.age;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "../struktur2/load.php",
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
              items = json;
            },
            error: function(e) {
              console.log("jQuery error message = "+e.message);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Original question was to parse a list of topics, however starting with the original example to have a function return a single value may also useful.  To that end, here is an example of (one way) to do that:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function getSingleValueUsingJQuery() {
      var value = "";
      var url = "rest/endpointName/" + document.getElementById('someJSPFieldName').value;
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
          console.log(json.value);   // needs to match the payload (i.e. json must have {value: "foo"}
          value = json.value;
        },
        error: function(e) {
          console.log("jQuery error message = "+e.message);
        }
      });
      return value;
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The data returned by the JSON is in json format : which is simply an arrays of values. Thats why you are seeing **[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]**.

You have to iterate through that values to get actuall value. Like the following

jQuery provides $.each() for iterations, so you could also do this:

```
$.getJSON("url_with_json_here", function(data){
    $.each(data, function (linktext, link) {
        console.log(linktext);
        console.log(link);
    });
});
```

Now just create an Hyperlink using that info.

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow code. This is help your code.

```
  $("#btnUpdate").on("click", function () {
            //alert("Alert Test");
            var url = 'http://cooktv.sndimg.com/webcook/sandbox/perf/topics.json';
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    debugger;

                    $.each(result.callback, function (index, value) {
                        alert(index + ': ' + value.Name);
                    });
                },
                failure: function (result) { alert('Fail'); }
            });
        });
```

I could not access your url. Bellow error is shows

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://cooktv.sndimg.com/webcook/sandbox/perf/topics.json. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:19829' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 501.